# Cannot install any extensions on GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, printing, extensions, shell

I'm currently trying to install the m.printws extension using "g.extension" command. However, it is giving me a FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'svn'. I tried other extensions too, yet non of them worked. Any idea of how to solve this issue?

Full Shell script:

```
 Fetching <m.printws> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1976, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1956, in main
    install_extension(source=source, url=url, xmlurl=xmlurl)
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 681, in install_extension
    ret1, installed_modules, tmp_dir = install_extension_std_platforms(module,
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1292, in install_extension_std_platforms
    download_source_code(source=source, url=url, name=name,
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1233, in download_source_code
    download_source_code_official_github(url, name, outdev, directory)
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1119, in download_source_code_official_github
    if grass.call(['svn', 'export',
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 74, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 63, in __init__
    subprocess.Popen.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'svn'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_lib_grass78_scripts_g.extension.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1976, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1956, in main
    install_extension(source=source, url=url, xmlurl=xmlurl)
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 681, in install_extension
    ret1, installed_modules, tmp_dir = install_extension_std_platforms(module,
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1292, in install_extension_std_platforms
    download_source_code(source=source, url=url, name=name,
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1233, in download_source_code
    download_source_code_official_github(url, name, outdev, directory)
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension", line 1119, in download_source_code_official_github
    if grass.call(['svn', 'export',
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 74, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/grass78/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 63, in __init__
    subprocess.Popen.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'svn'
```

Comment: You need to additionally install "subversion" - but normally that's being automatically by the installer. How did you install GRASS GIS?

Comment: I installed it from the command line  with "sudo apt-get install grass"!

Comment: I see. Likely you also need to install `sudo apt-get install grass-dev` to make `g.extension` happy. It might bring the needed dependencies.

Comment: Together with a "sudo apt-get update" it worked! Thanks a lot!